# Removing white padding from Wordpress template

Tags: html, css

I am trying to customise a wordpress theme. This is the template https://preview.metricthemes.com/inbox/

Using the inspector, you can remove the social media sidebar by deleting the

```
class="col col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-1 order-1 order-lg-1 order-md-1 order-xl-1 social-networks"
```

and then `div init` that appears when deleting the above. This will remove the social media bar on the left.

However, as seen on the picture, there is a white area that appears on the right when doing this [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47sj1.png). It seems to be padding, but I can't find how to remove that padding and make the third box from the left (the one with the main article), take that space.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a main content whose class is `post-content` so try the below CSS to make it from the left.

```
.post-content {
    padding-left: 0 65px 0 10px !important;
}
```

Also, you need to make a grid total of **12** so if you are removing the first column div then make changes for the fourth div and change the `col col-lg-6 col-xl-6` to `col col-lg-7 col-xl-7`

Comment: No luck unfortunately, but post-content does seem to be the class that refers to this block, will have a play with it

Comment: It seems to move the text to the left, but doesnt get rid of the white element box on the right (dotted purple in the image in my post)

Comment: I'm exaggerating with 150px left padding, but as you can see, the content gets pushed into the white area on the right https://imgur.com/a/KsG9ZSq

Comment: Changing the col from 6 to 7 did the trick, thank you!